# Javascript syntax error when printing HTML as string from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

From within PHP, I want at a certain point to change the content of a DIV called "menu".
In PHP, I do the following:

```
echo "<script> document.getElementById(\"menu\").innerHTML = \"NewContent\"; </script>";
```

And it perfectly works.
Then, things get more complicated, and I have a function that "creates" a piece of HTML, like this:

```
function createNewDiv() {
  $o =  "<a href=\"example.html\">Click 'here'</a>";
  $o. = "<i onclick=\" $(\"#maindiv\").load('another.php'); return false; \">XXX</i>";
  $o .= "<b>... and much, much more...</b>";
  return $o;
}
```

In another area of the page, I do:

```
echo createNewDiv();
```

and it prints nicely, no syntax error whatsoever.

If I now try to do something like this:

```
echo "<script> document.getElementById(\"menu\").innerHTML = \"".createNewDiv()."\"; </script>";
```

it stops working with some syntax error (from the browser) due to strings that are interrupted "somewhere" by some quotes/double quotes.
I guess I must escape the quotes/double quotes somehow, I tried with [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) but it did not work. 
Then I realized I only needed to escape the double quotes, so I did

```
$escaped = str_replace("\"", "\\\"", createNewDiv());
echo "<script> document.getElementById(\"menu\").innerHTML = \"$escaped\"; </script>";
```

But still it doesn't work! I know it's a truncated string somewhere, but unfortunately I cannot access the source because it's in an AJAX-updated div and the browser only shows me the main page.

I am just going mad thinking about the first function output, going into the str_replace, then into innerHTML, then printed by PHP, then interpreted by the browser... And I get lost "where" the quotes should be escaped ;)

Comment: You can inspect the DOM in the browsers developer tools if you need to inspect the updated HTML, and under "Network" you can inpect the contents of requests if you need to see contents of an AJAX request before inserting it into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested double-quotes in:

```
$o. = "<i onclick=\" $(\"#maindiv\").load('another.php'); return false; \">XXX</i>";
```

It outputs:

```
<i onclick=" $("#maindiv").load('another.php'); return false; ">XXX</i>
```

Replace inner double quotes (around `#maindiv`) with single quotes:

```
<i onclick=" $('#maindiv').load('another.php'); return false; ">XXX</i>
```

or replace nested double-quotes with the `&quot;` entity:

```
<i onclick=" $(&quot;#maindiv&quot;).load('another.php'); return false; ">XXX</i>
```

To make such replacement automatically, use the PHP's built-in [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.

By the way, during debug, it's generally a good idea to separate client side from server side. First make static HTML working, then convert it to a server-side scripted one. And consider using a template engine instead of hardcoding HTML into PHP code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I made a mistake writing the example. In my "real" code, there is no nested double quotes, otherwise the function by itself would not work (when I simply echo createNewDiv();
I tried to make a way simpler example here keeping the "concept" of the problem intact. PS: thank you for the hint about the template engine, but I have no idea what you are talking about :) Can you provide a link with "the best" template engine you know? Thank you :)

Comment: The PHP function does work since your nested double quotes are escaped in PHP code. But they are OUTPUT not escaped (and escaping with slashes wouln't work; in HTML, entities like `&quot;` should be used to escape special characters), so browser closes the HTML attribute once it encounters the first nested double-quote.

Comment: It took me a while to digest all :) ok, so the question now is: is there a PHP function like replace_double_nested_quotes_with_&quot ? (of course, the name is just a joke, I know "&" is not a valid character in a function name). I am asking because I do not want to do it by hand and every time I change the createNewDiv() function.

Comment: @ZioBit *"but I made a mistake writing the example"* - then please update it accordingly. I give you -1 until you do so

Comment: @ZioBit Use the `htmlspecialchars()` function. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @TomášZato I made a mistake writing that I made a mistake... Meaning that I was thinking I made a mistake because there was no nested double quotes, but then probably there are... I was under the impression that SINCE printing the output IS WORKING, then there couldn't be nested double quotes. But there are due to what it's been explained to me.

Comment: @ZioBit oh well. I'll post some random edit on your post so that I can undownvote it (vote is locked by now).

Comment: @TomášZato No big deal, as long as I can get answers, some downvotes do not bother me :) But thank you for taking the time to do it. I am trying to implement the proposed solution but it's better I go to bed and try it tomorrow morning :)